# How to move Postresql to RAM disk in Docker?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I want to run the Docker image `postgres:9`, stop Postgres, move it to `/dev/shm`, and restart it, so I can run my application tests really fast.

But when I try to stop Postgres in the container using `postgres` or `pg_ctl` I get told `cannot be run as root`.

**Since all Docker containers log you in as the root user what can I do to run the Postgres commands I need?**

And which folders do I need to move to `/dev/shm` before restarting it?

---

Command to start the container if you want to try this:

`docker run -it postgres:9 bash
cd /usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin
./pg_ctl stop`

Comment: Can't you run `su - postgres -c 'pg_ctl stop'`?

Comment: That tells me `pg_ctl: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" is not a database cluster directory`

Comment: Then you need to figure out where your PostgreSQL data directory is and specify that via the `-D` switch. Didn't you read the `pg_ctl` documentation?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Mount a [tmpfs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#tmpfs-mount-tmpfs-filesystems) in the container and point the [PostgreSQL](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) data at it

```bash
docker run --tmpfs=/pgtmpfs -e PGDATA=/pgtmpfs postgres:15
```

Use `size=Nk` to set a size limit (rather than all free memory).

```bash
--tmpfs /pgtmpfs:size=131072k
```

The same can be done for MySQL

```bash
docker run --tmpfs=/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes mysql:8
```

#### Kubernetes

[An `emptyDir` volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#emptydirvolumesource-v1-core) can set the medium property to `Memory`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: tmpfs-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: docker.io/postgres:15
    name: tmpdb
    env:
    - name: PGDATA
      value: /pgtmpfs
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /pgtmpfs
      name: tmpdata-volume
  volumes:
  - name: tmpdata-volume
    emptyDir:
      medium: Memory
      sizeLimit: 131072k
```

#### Docker Compose

And in a [docker compose 3.6+](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#tmpfs) definition (not supported by `stack`)

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  db:
    image: docker.io/postgres:15
    environment:
      - PGDATA=/pgtmpfs
    tmpfs:
      - /pgtmpfs
```

Compose can define shared volumes of `tmpfs` as well.

Comment: Thanks, it runs perfectly. However, how do I make sure it did run on the RAM disk?

Comment: `docker exec $MYSQL_CONTAINER df /var/lib/mysql`

Comment: @Matt compose sample is a bit misleading. `tmpfs` part should use `/pgtmpfs` as its not gonna work.

Answer (score 0):

By adding --user=postgres
to your docker parameter list, you'll get to be user=postgres directly:

```
docker --user=postgres run -it postgres:9 bash
cd /usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin
./pg_ctl stop
```